# HTMX websocket target response element

Tags: html, htmx

Using `HTMX` with `Django` and `websocket`.

```html
{% block content %}

<main hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws/attempt/{{ id }}/" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#question_response">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">

            <div id="question_response"></div>

      </div
    </div>

  </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

But the response is not rendering in target `div`. I want the response to render in `question_response` div.

The `HTMX` guide only has the following code block but does not describe how to target response.

```html
<div hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/chatroom">
    <div id="notifications"></div>
    <div id="chat_room">
        ...
    </div>
    <form id="form" ws-send>
        <input name="chat_message">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you are sending data from Django via WebSocket in a format that HTMX expects and that you're targeting the correct element.

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws/attempt/{{ id }}/" hx-trigger="load" ws-target="#question_response">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-4">
        <div id="question_response"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

I've added `ws-target="#question_response"` to indicate the target for WebSocket messages. Make sure your Django WebSocket backend is correctly configured to send data to `/ws/attempt/{{ id }}/`.

Hope this helps.

- If your response from the backend is plain text, you may need to handle it manually via JavaScript to update the `question_response` div.

```js
// JavaScript
document.addEventListener("htmx:wsMessage", function (event) {
  if (event.detail.wsTarget === "#question_response") {
    document.querySelector("#question_response").innerHTML = event.detail.data;
  }
});
```

Attach this JavaScript to handle incoming WebSocket messages and update the `#question_response` div's content. Make sure to include this script in your HTML.

Comment: It is not working. The response from the backend is text data.